Failed ADF Copy Activity
The source is an on-prem SQL data base and the sink is Azure SQL Database (Synapse).  I am recieving the following errror:
Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=PdwManagedToNativeInteropException ErrorNumber: 46724, MajorCode: 467, MinorCode: 24, Severity: 20, State: 2, Exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Tds.PdwManagedToNativeInteropException' was thrown.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=100000,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=100000,State=1,Message=PdwManagedToNativeInteropException ErrorNumber: 46724, MajorCode: 467, MinorCode: 24, Severity: 20, State: 2, Exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Tds.PdwManagedToNativeInteropException' was thrown.,},],'

It is copying 80,397 of 83,972 rows.  So I set parallelism to 1 and added an order by clause so I could identify the bad row.  I excluded what I thought was the bad row from the source query but it still failed with the same error.  I then included only that bad row and it worked.
Nothing appeared wrong with that row anyway.  So either I have the wrong row or this is not a datatype issue.  How do I get DF to give me more details of the error so I can see what's going wrong?

Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=PdwManagedToNativeInteropException ErrorNumber: 46724, MajorCode: 467, MinorCode: 24, Severity: 20, State: 2, Exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Tds.PdwManagedToNativeInteropException' was thrown.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=100000,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=100000,State=1,Message=PdwManagedToNativeInteropException ErrorNumber: 46724, MajorCode: 467, MinorCode: 24, Severity: 20, State: 2, Exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Tds.PdwManagedToNativeInteropException' was thrown.,},],'

According to this

The above error occurs when one or more columns of destination have defined size lesser than the data which you are trying to copy. Try increasing the size of the columns.

To resolve the above error If you aware of the columns in sink modify the size of the columns using below code:
alter table table_name alter column columne_name datatype NULL
Note - The error message does not give details about the column or row because of which copy activity fails. You need to figure that out manually.
To figure out the error, that means which columns are failed to insert, go to settings, enable the staging in settings and give a path for blob staging storage as shown below:

For more information you can refer to the similar question.

Thanks.  I enabled staging, and logging.  But it doesnt idicate which row failed.  I am not seeing any error in any of the resulting files produced by logging.
